# Custom 404 page to find out the link

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-status-code-404

I am looking to create a 404 page that can retrieve the page URL. I have tried using UrlReferer but this returned null. If I can find the URL I can create the relevant redirect.

Thanks

Comment: It's not all that clear what you are trying to do. The user followed an invalid URL that results in a 404. Where are you going to redirect them to?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the link might of existed previously as a lot of pages have been moved around due to new categories in the site

Answer (score 0):

If you use [response rewriting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.customerrorssection.redirectmode.aspx) in your web.config, you'll be on the correct URL already:

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" 
    defaultRedirect="~/content/Error.aspx">
```